# fabric.js - Circle don't work if properties defined outside of new fabric.Circle() brackets

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

When I create a new circle object wit properties in the brackets no problem appears when a circle needs to be generated. (old way)

```
function vanillaObjectFunc(type) {

    if (type === 'Rect') {
        var tObject = new fabric.Rect({
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            opacity: 0.8,
            fill: 'black',
            left: canvasB.width / 2,
            top: canvasB.height / 2
        });
    } else {
        var tObject = new fabric.Circle({
            radius: 20,
            opacity: 0.8,
            fill: 'black',
            left: canvasB.width / 2,
            top: canvasB.height / 2
        });
    }

    canvasB.getObjects();
    canvasB.add(tObject);
    canvasB.selection = false;
    canvasB.renderAll();
    canvasB.calcOffset();
}
```

But now in a dynamically function which defines all properties after creating the circle object and add the circle on the canvas, should look like: (new way)

```
function newObjectFunc(type) {

    var tObject = new fabric[type]({});

    tObject['opacity'] = 0.8;
    tObject['fill'] = 'black';
    tObject['left'] = canvasA.width / 2;
    tObject['top'] = canvasA.height / 2;


    if (type == 'Circle') {
        tObject['radius'] = 100;
    } else if (type == 'Rect') {
        tObject['width'] = 50;
        tObject['height'] = 50;
    }

    canvasA.getObjects();
    canvasA.add(tObject);
    canvasA.selection = false;
    canvasA.renderAll();
    canvasA.calcOffset();
}
```

Looking easy, but there is some strange issue, because Circle don't gets generated, this way and I don't found a reason why.

The properties are the same.
Console.log of the circle-object (new way) looks correct, too.

[https://jsfiddle.net/*Sascha*/052jnLu6/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/_Sascha_/052jnLu6/2/)

What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this situation, you should avoid direct property assignment and use [fabric.Object.set()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#set) instead:

```
tObject.set({
    opacity: 0.8,
    fill: 'black',
    left: canvasA.width / 2,
    top: canvasA.height / 2
});

if (type == 'Circle') {
    tObject.set('radius', 100);
} else if (type == 'Rect') {
    tObject.set({
        width: 50,
        height: 50
    });
}
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/052jnLu6/3/).